# Terracotta server stuck at DIAGNOSTIC state

Tags: spring-boot, distributed-caching, terracotta, ehcache-3

I am trying to run Terracotta server 10.11 from https://www.terracotta.org/downloads/ to connect it with Ehcache in my Spring boot application. But the problem is that when i run Terracotta server instance using the server\bin\start-tc-server.bat it does not give any error but put the server in DIAGNOSTIC state as shown in logs below.

```
2022-11-24 14:22:01,660 INFO - Terracotta 5.8.5, as of 2021-12-16 at 22:21:34 UTC (Revision 3695ab2f870d94491c564e87c266555a7d1c096b from UNKNOWN)
2022-11-24 14:22:01,660 INFO - Extensions:
2022-11-24 14:22:01,679 INFO - PID is 23344
2022-11-24 14:22:01,965 INFO - Did not find configuration directory at: C:\Users\user\terracotta\config
2022-11-24 14:22:01,965 INFO - Starting node from config file: C:\Users\user\Downloads\ehcache-clustered-3.10.0-kit\ehcache-clustered-3.10.0-kit\server\conf\cluster.cfg
2022-11-24 14:22:02,266 INFO - Found only one node information in config file: C:\Users\user\Downloads\ehcache-clustered-3.10.0-kit\ehcache-clustered-3.10.0-kit\server\conf\cluster.cfg
2022-11-24 14:22:02,267 INFO - Starting unconfigured node: default-node
2022-11-24 14:22:02,271 INFO - Bootstrapped nomad system with root: C:\Users\user\terracotta\config
2022-11-24 14:22:02,277 INFO - Startup configuration of the node:

client-lease-duration=150s
client-reconnect-window=120s
cluster-name=clustered
failover-priority=availability
offheap-resources=main\:512MB
stripe.1.node.1.bind-address=0.0.0.0
stripe.1.node.1.group-bind-address=0.0.0.0
stripe.1.node.1.group-port=9430
stripe.1.node.1.hostname=localhost
stripe.1.node.1.log-dir=%H/terracotta/logs
stripe.1.node.1.name=default-node
stripe.1.node.1.port=9410
stripe.1.stripe-name=default-stripe
2022-11-24 14:22:02,280 INFO - Logging directory is not set. Logging only to the console
2022-11-24 14:22:02,293 INFO - Available Max Runtime Memory: 1820MB
2022-11-24 14:22:02,314 INFO - Creating server nodeID: NodeID[localhost:9410]
2022-11-24 14:22:02,546 INFO - Initializing LeaseServiceProvider with default lease length of 150000 ms
2022-11-24 14:22:02,548 INFO - Initializing org.terracotta.lease.service.LeaseServiceProvider@4cf92ef3
2022-11-24 14:22:02,549 INFO - Initializing org.terracotta.client.message.tracker.OOOMessageHandlerProvider@40f5b3f9
2022-11-24 14:22:02,556 INFO - Registered MBean with name: DiagnosticRequestHandler
2022-11-24 14:22:02,557 INFO - Registered Diagnostic Service: org.terracotta.nomad.server.NomadServer
2022-11-24 14:22:02,557 INFO - Registered Diagnostic Service: org.terracotta.dynamic_config.api.service.DynamicConfigService
2022-11-24 14:22:02,558 INFO - Registered Diagnostic Service: org.terracotta.dynamic_config.api.service.TopologyService
2022-11-24 14:22:02,558 INFO - Initializing org.terracotta.diagnostic.server.DiagnosticServiceProvider@1bf35727
2022-11-24 14:22:02,561 INFO - Initializing org.terracotta.diagnostic.server.extensions.DiagnosticExtensionsServiceProvider@410ee45a
2022-11-24 14:22:02,804 INFO - Initializing org.terracotta.management.service.monitoring.MonitoringServiceProvider@65c7455b
2022-11-24 14:22:02,804 INFO - Initializing org.terracotta.platform.ServerInfoProvider@240d561b
2022-11-24 14:22:02,806 INFO - Registered dynamic configuration change handler for setting client-reconnect-window: org.terracotta.dynamic_config.server.service.handler.ClientReconnectWindowConfigChangeHandler@74d20602
2022-11-24 14:22:02,809 INFO - Registered dynamic configuration change handler for setting log-dir: org.terracotta.dynamic_config.server.service.handler.NodeLogDirChangeHandler@67c6fc00
2022-11-24 14:22:02,810 INFO - Registered dynamic configuration change handler for setting failover-priority: ConfigChangeHandler#accept()
2022-11-24 14:22:02,810 INFO - Registered dynamic configuration change handler for setting public-hostname: ConfigChangeHandler#accept()
2022-11-24 14:22:02,811 INFO - Registered dynamic configuration change handler for setting public-port: ConfigChangeHandler#accept()
2022-11-24 14:22:02,811 INFO - Registered dynamic configuration change handler for setting cluster-name: ConfigChangeHandler#accept()
2022-11-24 14:22:02,812 INFO - Registered dynamic configuration change handler for setting lock-context: ConfigChangeHandler#accept()
2022-11-24 14:22:02,812 INFO - Registered dynamic configuration change handler for setting logger-overrides: org.terracotta.dynamic_config.server.service.handler.LoggerOverrideConfigChangeHandler@3ba87843
2022-11-24 14:22:02,813 INFO - Registered dynamic configuration change handler for setting tc-properties: org.terracotta.dynamic_config.server.api.SelectingConfigChangeHandler@16df9889
2022-11-24 14:22:02,815 INFO - Initializing org.terracotta.dynamic_config.server.service.DynamicConfigServiceProvider@29ca0612
2022-11-24 14:22:02,815 INFO - Registering implementation-provided service com.tc.services.PlatformServiceProvider@16b645b2
2022-11-24 14:22:02,816 INFO - Registering implementation-provided service com.tc.services.EntityMessengerProvider@3c352805
2022-11-24 14:22:02,816 INFO - Initializing com.tc.objectserver.persistence.NullPlatformStorageServiceProvider@149f57c4
2022-11-24 14:22:02,818 INFO - Registering implementation-provided service com.tc.services.LocalMonitoringProducer@5baa3715
2022-11-24 14:22:02,830 INFO - Creating 4 worker comm threads for default-node - L2_L1
2022-11-24 14:22:02,910 INFO - Registering implementation-provided service com.tc.services.CommunicatorService@7d51aa32
2022-11-24 14:22:02,920 INFO - HealthChecker Started
2022-11-24 14:22:02,952 INFO - Started the server in diagnostic mode
2022-11-24 14:22:02,967 INFO - Server started as default-node
2022-11-24 14:22:02,959 INFO - Terracotta Server instance has started diagnostic listening on  all interfaces (address:/0.0.0.0 port:9410)
2022-11-24 14:22:03,177 INFO - Moved to State[ DIAGNOSTIC ]
```

According to the documentation it should be in ACTIVE state to be running properly. Still i tried to make connection with the server from my Spring boot application but it was also unable to reach it and gave TimeoutException.

I am using the following command to run the server instance:
`./start-tc-server.bat -f  C:\Users\user\Downloads\ehcache-clustered-3.10.0-kit\ehcache-clustered-3.10.0-kit\server\conf\cluster.cfg`

Does anyone have any clue why its not getting to ACTIVE state ? maybe try to run it on your end and see if the server gets to ACTIVE state. Or is there anything i am missing ?
Thanks in Advance.

P.S I tried running older version of Terracotta server from the same downloads page and it easily goes to active state but i cannot use old version since it is not compaitable with Ehcache 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the server.

In the kit that you downloaded navigate to */tools/bin* and you need to run `config-tool.bat activate -f ../../server/conf/cluster.cfg`

This will create a folder `C:\Users\{user}\terracotta` that will contain the configs and logs for the terracotta server, so the next time you start it will use the configs in the folder and automatically go to activate state.

If you need to change configs delete the folder, restart terracotta and activate it again using the config tool.